# XOR in Java Lambda Expression for a List of boolean

Tags: java, lambda, xor

I started to try out Labda Expressions for implementing Boolean-Gates for a list of boolean input paramter.
For "or" and "and" I wrote the following statments:

OR: `expressions.stream().anyMatch(e -> e.evaluate(input));`

AND: `expressions.stream().allMatch(e -> e.evaluate(input));`

`e.evaluate(input)` returns true or false.
But since there is no onceMatch method allready implemented I am stuck with the XOR.

First idea would be to filter all true values and check if it is just one:

```
return expressions.stream().filter(e -> e.evaluate(input) == true).collect(Collectors.counting()) == 1;
```

But I would like to see it in one lambda expression.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to know whether there is exactly one match, you can use

```
expressions.stream().filter(e -> e.evaluate(input)).limit(2).count() == 1
```

the `limit(2)` avoids unnecessary processing, as once you encountered two matches, you already know that the result can’t be `==1`, without needing to count the other matches.

However, that’s not “XOR” logic, not even remotely. If you want an XOR operation, you may use

```
expressions.stream().map(e -> e.evaluate(input)).reduce((a,b) -> a^b).orElse(Boolean.FALSE)
```

Unlike AND or OR, there is no way to short-circuit an XOR operation.

Comment: Could you explain why the first expression is not XOR and what the second does? I understand that map creates a stream of boolean-values: e.g. [true, false, false, true] but after that I am stuck. Exspecially the "a^b" part. Isn't it a bitvise xor?

Comment: E.g. `true ^ true ^ true  ==  true` despite not having exactly one `true` input. From there, you may derive an infinite number of examples by simply replacing one `true` with `true ^ false`, repeatedly if you wish, e.g. replacing the first `true`, we get `true ^ false ^ true ^ true` which is also `true`. XOR simply does not imply “exactly one `true` value”…

Comment: There is no difference between “bitwise xor” and “logical xor”. Just set `0` for `false` and `1` for `true` and the results will be exactly the same…

Comment: Keep in mind, that your XOR implementation here also returns true when the input stream only has a single element that maps to true, I would rather go with a collect(toSet()).size() == 2 or so.

Comment: or event better expressions.stream().map(e -> e.evaluate(input)).distinct.count() == 2L

Comment: @ThomasFrick I’m not sure, which problem your suggestions are trying to solve. You are right in that they are different from what xor does, but why are you assuming that this is what the OP wanted?

Comment: @Holger I think, usually when people use an XOR they want to have it to return true only if an odd number of inputs are true, but you are right, this is an assumption and I might be wrong.

Comment: @ThomasFrick well, it was recognizable from the question that the OP wanted to check whether there is exactly one match and my answer already addresses the point that using xor is not the right approach for the task.

Answer (score 1):

I can't come up with a lambda expression that would suit your needs, but a slight refactoring of your first idea looks fine to me:

```
return expressions.stream().filter(e -> e.evaluate(input)).count() == 1;
```

Comment: well, thats indeed better! Thanks so far!